# Positional problems with vuetify speed dial

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am wanting to use the vuetify speeddial component in my app, but I am getting wierd positioning errors, what I am wanting is the button to be clicked and then the additional options slide to the left of it, [image]

As you can see from the image above they are positioned on the left but far to far from the original "parent" button, I have attemped to make a codesandbox but the results are inconclusive.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-gwtkc?file=/src/components/SpeedDial.vue

And finally here is my component code,

```
<template>
    <v-speed-dial
        v-model="fab"
        direction="left"
        transition="slide-x-reverse-transition"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-btn
            v-model="fab"
            color="blue darken-2"
            dark
            fab
          >
            <v-icon v-if="fab">mdi-close</v-icon>
            <v-icon v-else>mdi-account-circle</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        
        <v-btn fab dark small color="green">
            <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn fab dark small color="indigo">
            <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn fab dark small color="red">
            <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
                    
      </v-speed-dial>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    name: 'QuickSpeedDial',
    data() {
        return {
            fab: false,
            tabs: null
        }
    },
    computed: {
        activeFab () {
            switch (this.tabs) {
                case 'one': return { class: 'purple', icon: 'account_circle' }
                case 'two': return { class: 'red', icon: 'edit' }
                case 'three': return { class: 'green', icon: 'keyboard_arrow_up' }
                default: return {}
            }
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a style as it says on the official website.

```
...

<style>
.v-speed-dial {
  position: absolute;
}
.v-btn--floating {
  position: relative;
}
</style>

...
```